# Gradle - show deprecated API warnings for Groovy compilation

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm using Gradle 3.1 and have tests with Spockframework (i.e. written in Groovy). I can turn on deprecation warnings for Java files (even when the Java class is in a Groovy source set), so this part is fine - I turned it on with `AbstractCompile.options.deprecation = true`.
However, there seems to be no way to turn it on for Groovy compilation, at least I don't see anything in GroovyCompileOptions (i.e. `GroovyCompile.groovyOptions`).

Is there a way to have deprecations shown for Groovy compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of groovy are you using? (type `gradle -version` at command line)

I'd guess this should work with groovy 1.6.4+

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) { task ->
    task.options.deprecation = true
}
```

Comment: This only turns on deprecations for Java classes from src/main/groovy during join-compilation, and is already turned on by setting AbstractCompile.options.deprecations, as mentioned in the post. Also, the Groovy compiler (*.groovy files) is configured using GroovyCompileOptions according to the docs (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile.html).

Comment: I use Gradle 3.1 and `gradle --version` says it bundles 2.4.7, but it has nothing to do with source compilation, see here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#sec:groovy_dependency_management (I'm not using localGroovy() as a dependency).

Comment: This also shows any deprecations in the temporarily generated java files, so I can trace them back to the groovy files. Thanks!